Adding a boundary to an ideal doesn't change homology
Suppose that we have a differential graded associative algebra $(A,d)$, a differential graded ideal $I \subseteq A$ and a boundary $dx \in A$ (we can assume $dx \notin I$). $A$ can be assumed to be free.
Under what assumptions (on $A$, $dx$, or $I$...) does the inclusion $I \subseteq I + (dx)$ induce an isomorphism on homology?
It suffices to be shown (I think) that given an arbitrary $\sum_i a_i dx b_i \in (dx)$, if $d\sum_i a_i dx b_i = 0$ then $\sum_i a_i dx b_i = dç$ for some boundary $dç \in I + (dx)$.
Any help would be appreciated. I can also consider a different kind of algebra (something like a coloured algebra): there are elements of $A$ of colour (1,1), elements of colour (1,2) and elements of colour (2,2), but none of colour (2,1). Elements of colour $(m,n)$ can only be multiplied with elements of colour $(n,k)$, in which case an element of colour $(m,k)$ arises. The differential respects colours. And $x$ is of colour $(1,2)$. Note that in this setting the $a_i$ in the formula above must be of colour (1,1), and the $b_i$ of colour (2,2).
** EDIT:
Here an idea that I've been exploring. There's the short exact sequence of differential graded modules $$0 \to I \to I + (dx) \to \frac{I+(dx)}{I} \to 0.$$
It induces a long exact sequence on homology, and for $H_*(I) \cong H_*(I + (dx))$ it suffices to show that $(I+(dx))/I$ is acyclic. By an isomorphism theorem, this differential graded module is isomorphic to $(dx)/(I \cap (dx))$.
This last dg-module fits in another short exact sequence $$0 \to I \cap (dx) \to (dx) \to \frac{(dx)}{I \cap (dx)} \to 0,$$
which again induces a long exact sequence on homology. The acyclicity of $(dx)/(I \cap (dx))$ would follow from the acyclicity of $I \cap (dx)$ and $(dx)$. I don't know whether I'm just beating around the bush or this is actually useful.
